# Trouble with cloning in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

In a form that needs a variant number of band members I am using the following code on a button to duplicate an input.

A snippet of the HTML is this:

```
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
    <label for="band_member">Band Member: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="  add another member  " />
</div>
```

And this jquery is in the document ready function:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
newElem.children(':first').attr( 'val', '' ).attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
$('#input' + num).after(newElem);
$("#band_member_count").val( newNum );             
}); // end btnAdd click
```

When the form is submitted, the added inputs aren't being submitted with the last entry becoming the value of the first input and the value of each newly added input is not being cleared like the code indicates.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason it isn't working is because you are adding the id="name" + num to the label, rather than the input and each input therefore has the same exact id.

Change the first selector to input selector:

```
newElem.children(':first').attr( 'val', '' ).attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
```

should be:

```
newElem.find('input').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum).val("");
```

Comment: I changed it as you said but it didn't work. However, following your logic I changed it to this: newElem.find('input').attr( 'val', '' ).attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum); and it now submits all values (THANKS!!!) But the value still isn't cleared on the clone. Thoughts?

Comment: @jgravois Change it to this: newElem.find('input').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum).val("");  I also updated my answer to reflect this change.